# Newsletter signup window

Tags: php, css, wordpress, newsletter, mailchimp

No idea how to go about this. Apologies if it's a stupid question (probably is!)...

I'm going to add a newsletter link to the homepage. I want this tag to trigger a MailChimp newsletter signup form that will open on the same page. I don't want users to be redirected to a new page to signup. I've had a look around but can't find anything that would give me this style.

Any help would be appreciated. Really stumped on this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using jQuery you can do something like this

```
<span id="newsletter">Sign Up For My Newsletter</span>
<div id="signUpForm" style="display:none;">
    Mail Chimp Code Goes Here <span id="closeSignupForm" style="color: red;">X</span>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#newsletter').click(function() {
        $('#signUpForm').show();
    })
    $('#closeSignupForm').click(function() {
        $('#signUpForm').hide();
    })
</script>
```

Comment: This is ideal @stefan, thanks! How do I get it to close on click? Once I click on it once, I can't hide the form by clicking on it again.